# scrolling home menu nog working on detail page

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, scroll, menu

We are building a one pager website with a detail page to the protfolio items. Now we have the menu scrolling on the homepage to the content on that page.

So i'm having the menu items ike this.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="section-1">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="section-2">Section 2</a></li>
<li><a href="section-3">Section 3</a></li>
<li><a href="section-4">Section 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The content divs are build up like this

```
<div id="section-1">Content</div>
```

Now here is the jquery i'm using, which is working fine on the homepage

```
// Function: Scroll navigation to row
$('.navbar a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $row = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($row.offset().top - menuHeight - 78) 
    }, 1000);
});
```

So now when i'm on the detail page i just want to click on any menu item and then go back to the homepage at the right content.

But clicking on that wont work, i'm getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (website.js:26)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery.js:3)
```

I tried some many things already, adding the absolute path to the url, but i would like to work around with that, because it wont scroll to the content then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `$(this).attr('href')` output will be `section-1` You need to use `#`

```
var $row = $('#' + $(this).attr('href'));
```

**OR** *or not and* you need to add `#` in href for all links like

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

> Note: This code will work if all the elements in the same page

And about your question about *on the detail page i just want to click on any menu item and then go back to the homepage at the right content.*

let's start doing that

**1st**: You need to check the url for `detail` page if its the `detail` page stop `click` event

So we will assume you `detail` page is `detail.html`

On html

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

on Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var menuHeight = $('.navbar a').outerHeight(true);
   // Function: Scroll navigation to row
   $('.navbar a').on('click', function(e) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("detail.html") === -1) { // if url dosen't have the detail page so active the click event
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent redirect
      var $href = $(this).attr('href'); // get href
      var section = $('#' + $href.substr($href.indexOf("#") + 1));  // get the section from href
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (section.offset().top - menuHeight - 78)
      }, 1000);
     }
  });
  // on load
   var url = window.location.href;  // get the page url
   if(window.location.hash.substr(1) !== ''){
     var section = window.location.hash.substr(1);  // get the section after the `#` on url
     $('.navbar a[href*='+section+']').click(); // if url href with this section trigger click it
   }
});
```

And here is how your code should work on index page

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var menuHeight = $('.navbar a').outerHeight(true);
   // Function: Scroll navigation to row
   $('.navbar a').on('click', function(e) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("detail.html") === -1) { // if url dosen't have the detail page so active the click event
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent redirect
      var $href = $(this).attr('href'); // get href
      var section = $('#' + $href.substr($href.indexOf("#") + 1));  // get the section from href
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (section.offset().top - menuHeight - 78)
      }, 1000);
     }
  });
  // on load
   var url = window.location.href;  // get the page url
   if(window.location.hash.substr(1) !== ''){
     var section = window.location.hash.substr(1);  // get the section after the `#` on url
     $('.navbar a[href*='+section+']').click(); // if url href with this section trigger click it
   }
});
```

```css
.navbar{
 position : fixed;
 background : yellow;
 top : 0;
 left:0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
div[id^=section]{
 background : red;
 margin : 30px;
 min-height: 300px;
}
#section-1{
 margin-top : 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="section-1">Section 1</div>
<div id="section-2">Section 2</div>
<div id="section-3">Section 3</div>
<div id="section-4">Section 4</div>
```

And this is for how your code should works if returned back from `detail` page

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = 'http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-2';
   var menuHeight = $('.navbar a').outerHeight(true);
   // Function: Scroll navigation to row
   $('.navbar a').on('click', function(e) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("detail.html") === -1) { // if url dosen't have the detail page so active the click event
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent redirect
      var $href = $(this).attr('href'); // get href
      var section = $('#' + $href.substr($href.indexOf("#") + 1));  // get the section from href
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (section.offset().top - menuHeight - 78)
      }, 1000);
     }
  });
  // on load
   //var url = window.location.href;  // get the page url
   //if(window.location.hash.substr(1) !== ''){
     var section = url.substr(url.indexOf("#") + 1);  // get the section after the `#` on url
   //alert(section);
     $('.navbar a[href*='+section+']').click(); // if url href with this section trigger click it
   //}
});
```

```css
.navbar{
 position : fixed;
 background : yellow;
 top : 0;
 left:0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
div[id^=section]{
 background : red;
 margin : 30px;
 min-height: 300px;
}
#section-1{
 margin-top : 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yourwebsite/index.html#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="section-1">Section 1</div>
<div id="section-2">Section 2</div>
<div id="section-3">Section 3</div>
<div id="section-4">Section 4</div>
```